# How do I make it so it will add/remove decimal points based on the current amount of digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**This is an example:**

```
var = float(input("Type something: "))
var2 = round(var,2)
```

I want to make it so if the user inputs a float where the max digit is the tenths place or less, it will add a 0 otherwise, it will print it rounded

**Examples:**

input: 4.6

output: 4.60

input: 7

output: 7.00

input: 5.43892

output: 5.44

Comment: I guess you looking for format spec `.2f`?

Answer (score 1):

.2f can help you. You might want to change the value 2 to others

```
var = float(input("Type something: "))
var2 = format(var,'.2f')
print(var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of @ILee, this format is also useful to print a variable.

```py
var = float(input("Type something: "))

print(f'{var:.2f}')
```